# Swagger UI doesn't display properly

Tags: swagger, jhipster

Using JHipster (and swagger-ui 2.1.5) I wanted to access the "API" tab.

However it doesn't seem to properly display and I get the following errors in the console :

```
index.html:8 GET http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/css/typography.css
index.html:10 GET http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/css/screen.css 
index.html:15 GET http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/lib/jquery.slideto.min.js 
index.html:14 GET http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/lib/jquery-1.8.0.min.js 
index.html:16 GET http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/lib/jquery.wiggle.min.js 
index.html:18 GET http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/lib/handlebars-2.0.0.js 
index.html:17 GET http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/lib/jquery.ba-bbq.min.js 
index.html:19 GET http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/lib/lodash.min.js 
index.html:21 GET http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/lib/swagger-ui.min.js 
index.html:13 GET http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/lib/object-assign-pollyfill.js 
index.html:22 GET http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/lib/highlight.9.1.0.pack.js 
index.html:20 GET http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/lib/backbone-min.js 
index.html:24 GET http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/lib/jsoneditor.min.js 
index.html:25 GET http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/lib/marked.js 
index.html:23 GET http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/lib/highlight.9.1.0.pack_extended.js 
index.html:26 GET http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/lib/swagger-oauth.js 
index.html:9 GET http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/css/reset.css 
index.html:12 GET http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/css/print.css 
index.html:14 GET http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/lib/jquery-1.8.0.min.js 
index.html:15 GET http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/lib/jquery.slideto.min.js 
index.html:16 GET http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/lib/jquery.wiggle.min.js 
index.html:17 GET http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/lib/jquery.ba-bbq.min.js 
index.html:18 GET http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/lib/handlebars-2.0.0.js 
index.html:19 GET http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/lib/lodash.min.js 
index.html:20 GET http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/lib/backbone-min.js 
index.html:21 GET http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/lib/swagger-ui.min.js 
index.html:22 GET http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/lib/highlight.9.1.0.pack.js 
index.html:23 GET http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/lib/highlight.9.1.0.pack_extended.js 
index.html:24 GET http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/lib/jsoneditor.min.js 
index.html:25 GET http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/lib/marked.js 
index.html:26 GET http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/lib/swagger-oauth.js
index.html:34 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at index.html:34
```

[image]

I am using Eclipse (STS distribution) and I fear it might be a project configuration problem but as I am fairly new to it I haven't been able to pinpoint the source of the issue.

**EDIT:**

I am using Maven and the error still occurs wether I launch the app via STS or command line.

The project is as generated except one service that I wanted to test out.

Furthermore I just generated a new JHipster app and the errors remain.

**EDIT':**

The display is indeed better on Edge where I have access to the services.

I also noted that the unchanged app displays well on Edge.

[image]

Comment: Your console log is strange, mine shows http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/dist/lib/jquery-1.8.0.min.js, difference is the 'dist' sub folder but I'm running on JHipster 4 (master). Have you tried to run in another browser?

Comment: Looking at swagger-ui/index.html in sample app generated by latest JHipster 3 you should see references to bower_components folder: https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app/blob/master/src/main/webapp/swagger-ui/index.html#L14  so I'm wondering which version you use

Comment: I am using JHipster Generator v3.12.2 and bower v1.8.0

Comment: I also have the exact same file you mentionned, at the same place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using another app to mimic its services and it was probably running older versions of JHipster, Swagger... and that made the problem appear again but this time on Edge.

Deleting the browser's cache files fixed the errors for Edge and Chrome.